# RDP problem with Vista and Windows 7 destination

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I use a server a home to host a bunch of concurrently running Hyper-V VM's with different OS's and software for testing.

I have Vista on the laptop, all latest SP's and patches. The server is Server 2008 R2, fully patched. The guests are a mix of XP, Vista, Server 2008 and Windows 7.

If I connect to the Win XP or Server 2008 guest using RDP, it is always good. Very quick, no speed issues.

If I connect to the Vista or Win 7 guests, the response time is so slow it is unusable. Usually 6 or 8 seconds, and at times it is to long to measure! This happens from both the laptop running Vista, and the server running Server 2008 R2.

Does anyone know what the issue is with RDP on Vista and Windows 7 destinations?

I did read this: "http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/microsoft/remote-desktop-slow-problem-solved.asp" and that is not the problem I have applied that change to all PC's.

Comment: How is the speed if you RDP from one of the XP or Server 2008 guests to the Vista or Win 7 guests?

Comment: I have RDP'd from my Vista laptop into the Server 2008 R2 host, then connected to the Win7 guest using the Hyper-V manager, and in that session, RDP'd into the Windows Vista guest, and that worked great. No discernible lag. Yet when RDPing from my Vista lapto direct to the Vista guest, more than 7 seconds lag...

Answer (score 2):

Disable TCP/IP auto tuning.  Open an elevated command prompt and:

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```